# Does LinkedList in Java have a default iterator implemented?

Tags: java, interface, linked-list, iterator, iterable

I´m studying Java classes and inheritance and I had a doubt with interfaces.

LinkedList class implements Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable, Collection, Deque, List, Queue according to Oracle documentation.

Because Iterable is an interface and not a class like LinkedList, it must have implemented a default iterator, mustn´t it?
And if understood that right, where could I see the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, in the source code.

The longer answer is `LinkedList` itself does not need to implement the `iterator()` method if it inherits from another class which may implement it. If you look closer at the [javadoc for LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), you can see that LinkedList does not define the `iterator()` method, but as you implement `Iterable` it should be there. Looking at the end you can also see the section of inherited methods. Specifically look at "Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractSequentialList", where `iterator()` is listed.

So now we have determined that `iterator` is in fact in `java.util.AbstractSequentialList`. So to find the implementation you can look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.java?av=f) of `AbstractSequentialList` which is:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return listIterator();
}
```

Now as you see the implementation depends on the implementation of `listIterator()`. `LinkedList` does not implement the `listIterator()` method (it has one with one argument but this expects the no-argument method). So looking at the javadoc again we can find under "Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractList" that the `listIterator()` method is inherited from there. So looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractList.java?av=f) from `AbstractList`:

```
public ListIterator<E>  listIterator() {
    return listIterator(0);
}
```

Now, the `listIterator(int)` method is implemented in the `LinkedList` class. From the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java?av=f) of `LinkedList`:

```
 public ListIterator<E>  [More ...] listIterator(int index) {
     checkPositionIndex(index);
     return new ListItr(index);
 }
```

If you need to further analyze what is does, you can continue from there.

Comment: I knew that you can implement your own iterator (I have done it for a subject at university, but the class wasn´t LinkedList), but I wasn´t sure at all about a default implementation in LinkedList, now I am

Answer (score 3):

> Because Iterable is an interface and not a class like LinkedList, it
>   must have implemented a default iterator, mustn´t it?

not really, if the super class does override the method then the child class doesn't have to...

look at this:

```
interface IFoo {
    int getFoo();
}

class A implements IFoo {

    @Override
    public int getFoo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    // ...
}
class C extends A implements IFoo {
    // ...
}
```

note how Class c compiles fine even thoe(redundantly) implements Ifoo but doesnt overide the getFoo method(that is only possible cos `C extends A`)

---

the class looks like:

```
public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
```

so in the class hierarchy it looks like
[image]

where the AbstractCollection looks like:

```
 public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {
```

so there is where they do override the methods from `interface Iterable<T>`

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to implement the method beeing abstract. Actually, its `AbstractSequentialList` that really implement the `Iterator` to redirect to the `ListIterator` interface (implemented in the AbstractList).

Answer (score 0):

You will find the implementation of iterable interface methods in Linked List class itself.

Comment: OK but maybe you should include some code to make this a bona fide answer.

Answer (score 0):

So LinkedList class extends AbstractSequentialList class. This class has method which is called as iterator. Since LinkedList exteds the AbstractSequentialList class we can make use of iterator method.

```
public abstract class AbstractSequentialList<E>
extends AbstractList<E>{
  public Iterator<E> iterator(){
    //implementation
 }
}
```

Now LinkedList class extends the AbstractSequentialList class. so by making the object of LinkedList class we can make use of iterator method.

```
public class LinkedList<E>
extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, Serializable{
}
```